# Speed up woocomerce order admin search

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am using the following function to speed up woocommerce order admin search by searching in particular fields only:

```
function custom_woocommerce_shop_order_search_fields( $search_fields ) {
    if(!empty($search_field = $_GET['searchfield'])) {
      
      //not unsetting $search_fields because we will be returning it if none of the values match
      
      // No need to pass search fields as order id searched by default
      if($search_field === 'Order ID') {
      return array();
      }
      
      if($search_field === 'Phone') {
      return array('_billing_phone');
      }
      
      if($search_field === 'Email') {
      return array('_billing_email');
      }
      
      if($search_field === 'Tracking Number') {
      return array('_wcst_order_trackno');
      }
    }
    
    //if some random value was passed, return array with number and mail, order id is searched by default 
    
     unset( $search_fields );
    $search_fields[] = '_billing_phone';
    $search_fields[] = '_billing_email';

    return $search_fields;
    
 
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_shop_order_search_fields', 'custom_woocommerce_shop_order_search_fields' );
```

I need to narrow it down further to search in orders that were created in past 1 year only and not beyond that to speed it up. How to do this?

Comment: The search terms from this hook are passed to an SQL query, so it is a matter of adjusting that SQL query to your needs. If you search on your current hook in the WooCommerce files you will see how it works

Comment: Hi, this is the query that runs on search: 

`$wpdb->prepare(
       "SELECT DISTINCT p1.post_id FROM {$wpdb->postmeta} p1 WHERE p1.meta_value LIKE %s AND p1.meta_key IN ('" . implode( "','", array_map( 'esc_sql', $search_fields ) ) . "')", // @codingStandardsIgnoreLine
       '%' . $wpdb->esc_like( wc_clean( $term ) ) . '%'
      )`

How to optimize it as per the above question?

Answer (score 0):

This is a well-known problem in both the older and the newer HPOS version of WooCommerce.  The search feature lets a shop manager search orders, current and historic, for the customer’s name, address, email, and other data. It also searches the names of products and shows orders containing those products. On large sites with many orders, the search is astoundingly slow.

Why? It uses unanchored text searches. For example, if a customer’s email is `info@stackoverflow.com` and somebody searches for `stackoverflow` the search will find that customer’s orders. It does this using a notoriously slow SQL idiom: `value LIKE '%stackoverflow%'`. That idiom with `%` wildcard characters is the way SQL searches for the text string anywhere within the value.

A fix for the poor performance is to use anchored text searches. They use the similar, but much faster, SQL idiom `value LIKE 'stackoverflow%'`, without the leading `%` wildcard character. There’s a tradeoff, however. An anchored text search for `'stackoverflow'` won’t find orders from our example customer.

This `'query'` filter edits the search queries to use anchored instead of unanchored searches:

```php
  public function query( $query ) {

    return str_replace(
      array('.meta_value LIKE \'%',   'WHERE order_item_name LIKE \'%'),
      array('.meta_value LIKE \'',    'WHERE order_item_name LIKE \''),
      $query );
  }
```

A very simple plugin to activate and use this filter is [here](https://github.com/OllieJones/fast-woo-order-lookup).